# excel interop font change events

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have an excel add-in that is automated using c# code. I am trying to find an event be it workbook or worksheet in c# that will detect when the user will change a property. In my case I would like to know which event fires off in C# when the user changes the zoom value.

Comment: I don't thing there is such event.

Comment: so how can I know if the user changed the zoom value of the excel sheet